# How do I find the period of repetition of this modular equation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

**EDITED QUESTION:**

I have this equation $$\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)\,mod\, \frac{13}{5}$$

and I want to find period after which its value repeats.

It can be written as $$\left(\frac{3x+2}{3}\right)\,-\, \frac{13}{5}q = 0$$

I am equating it to some number (here I am equating it to zero to make the calculations simple), in order to find its period. And $q$ is the quotient of the mod process.

It can be simplified as $$15x+10=39q$$
It can be re-written as
$$(15x+10) \,mod \, 39$$

Its period is 39, but when I checked programmatically, its period is 13. I want the smallest interval as the period. Where is the mistake? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your computations are exact : the smallest period is $36$.

It is of interest to make a zoom on a smaller part. We can observe:

- that the curve is made of parabolic arcs, looking very irregular at this scale. Note that the range of values is $[0,1/3].$
- that, there is a rather unexpected phenomenon ; the local (aka as "windowed") frequency is increasing till value 4.5 ; there is a big contrast between "just before" 4.5 and "just after", this value,  a little as if the "aperiodic behavior" is all concentrated before this value and a kind of "reset" is done once value $4.5$ has been crossed. A further analysis is necessary.

[image]

Matlab program that has generated the figure:

> > ```
> > x=35.:0.0001:37.5;
> > fr=@(x,y)(x-y.*floor(x./y));
> > u=fr(fr(9*x/4,(3/5)).*fr(2*x/3,3),1/3);
> > plot(x,u);
> > ```

Comment: I don't think you zoomed out far enough. The stated period is 36 and your graph only goes to 2.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel You are right, I just noticed my error...

Comment: I have updated the graphics and the text.

Comment: @JeanMarie This method works except when there is a minus in numerator of mod operator right? I mean, something like ((9-x) % 2). Periodicity gets changed at x = 9. For all other complex cases it works I guess. Right ? – user3219492 48 mins ago

Comment: I have seen that the phenomenon occurs at a submultiple (4.5) of the period. I have modified my text in this direction.

Comment: About the questions you are asking, I will think about them.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes there is a change at 4.5 as you say but that doesn't affect the answer 36 right? The period as per the calculation matches the correct answer, right?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have edited the question now. For (x+(2/3))%(13/5) it does not seem to work

Comment: I confirm : the period of the function in your question is 36.

Comment: The thing is, the method I followed doesn't seem to work properly. And the posted thing doesn't seem to be the answer to my question (to my before and after edit question). Seems like there is a bug in my method. And that is what I asked help for. Not to verify the period as 36. So only I didn't click "ACCEPT BUTTON". Anyways thanks alot for all your time :)

Comment: Correct. Yes I have spent time of it, but with a great pleasure: your question is intriguing and interesting, and I thank you for it.