# Periodicity of given modular equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, periodic-functions, congruence-relations, almost-periodic-functions

I want to find the period of repetition of the following sequence

$$\left( \frac{x^2}{100}*\left (\frac{2x}{10} \,mod\,\,1\right) \right)\,mod \,1$$

My answer and actual answers are not matching.

The actual answer is 250. But my answer is 100.

My answer:

$\qquad\frac{2x}{10} \,mod\,\,1$  ===> $\frac{x}{5} \,mod\,\,1$

In this division process, let $q$ be the quotient.

So it can be written as
$$\frac{x}{5} \,-\,\,1*q = 0$$

I am equating it to zero in-order to find the period. It can again be re-written as 
$x-5q=0$  which can again be written as  $x \,mod\,5$. So its period is 5.

Now the whole original equation in the question can be written as

$$\left( \frac{x^2}{100}* (f(x)) \right)\,mod \,1$$ Here $f(x)$ is a periodic function of period $5$ (I mean our re-written expression from above lines).

**USING IDENTITY:** $(a\,b) mod \,n = [(a\,mod\,n)\,(b\,mod\,n)]\,mod\,n.$

One can rewrite the above expression as

$$\left(\left( \frac{x^2}{100}\,mod\,1\right)* (f(x)\,mod\,1) \right)\,mod \,1$$

By similar procedure followed above, I got the periodicity of  $\left( \frac{x^2}{100}\,mod\,1\right)$ to be $100$ and periodicity of $(f(x)\,mod\,1)$  is  $lcm(5, 1) = 5$.

So, finally, the entire expression is simplified as a product of two periodic functions of period 100 and 5 and mod 1 applied on them.

**NOTE:**
The product of two periodic functions is also periodic with a period which is LCM of the periods of the two functions.

So the period of this whole function is $lcm(\,lcm(100,\,5),\,1) = 100$ which is my answer.

But when checked programmatically, the period is 250.

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding since all elements $\pmod{1}$ are $0$...

Comment: Some similarities with your recent previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2271485)

Comment: @BBC3 No. It can be zero all time only when the numerator is an integer. Substitute x = 1, you will get remainder as 1/500 and not zero. Remember that mod can be a fraction also.

Comment: @JeanMarieIn that link, It did not get the necessary answer I feel. And moreover, the obtained and actual answers in that link are at least a multiple. But not so here.